# Iterate through children in JSON object in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

`vm.product` return this JSON;

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sample string 2",
      "customers": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "customerid": 10
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
        "customerid": 3
        }
]
    }
```

I want to do a `ng-repeat` on the customers, but how?

I tried `ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers"`

```
vm.customers = vm.product.customers
```

But this return `undefined`.

What is the correct way, that i am missing?

Comment: Problem is not in this code.

Comment: You mean $scope.vm.customers = $scope.vm.product.customers, right?

Comment: here's a working plnkr for you http://plnkr.co/edit/XXCo4K1L6ZmfT7vDC5yG . you are missing a ']' in your object

Comment: problem is in your JSON file . that you are getting ....can you please the right JSON ??

Comment: May be the right JSON file that you should get is 

{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sample string 2",
  "customers": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "customerid": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
    "customerid": 3
    }
    ]
}

Comment: you just missed the ] bracket

Comment: I'm guessing he's using `controller as`, so no `$scope` here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the object to the scope. Do this in the controller:

```
$scope.product = {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sample string 2",
      "customers": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "customerid": 10
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
        "customerid": 3
        }
      ]
    };
```

Then in the html you can do:

```
ng-repeat="customer in product.customers"
```

That or something close should work but I've not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers` to `ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.product.customers"`and removed `vm.customers = vm.product.customers` from the controller, and it worked. Not quite sure why the other did not work though.

Thank you all for the comments that led me to the answer :-)